# @Value annotation is not working with Infinitest 5.2.0 on STS 3.9.6

Tags: spring, junit4, spring-tool-suite, infinitest

JUnit tests are failing when triggered by Infinitest complaining about wrong configuration values.
E.g.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'databaseConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.data.mongodb.database' in value "${spring.data.mongodb.database}"
```

It seems, that application properties are not loaded, although they present in the resources folder and working fine when the tests are running manually.

I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.9.6 with Infinitest 5.2.0

The unit tests are annotated like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ChargeConsumerApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ChargeConsumerApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

    @Test
    public void applicationContextLoaded() {
    }

    @Test
    public void applicationContextTest() {
        ChargeConsumerApplication.main(new String[] {});
    }
}
```

Is it an STS problem or I need some extra configuration for Infinitest itself?

Comment: can you share a sample project?

Comment: "Is it an STS problem". You could try running the test from terminal outside of STS. If you see the same error there then its not a problem with STS.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I wanted to share a  sample project and realized that it works with that simple one. So now, I am investigating what makes it fail in a more complex test configuration.

Comment: I could reproduce the problem in this sample project: https://github.com/csorbazoli/sample.git
The application config file (in my case: application.yml) is placed in the java/main/resources and in the java/test/resources also
The latter one hast the settings for test profile referenced by @ActiveProfiles(profiles="test") annotation. Which works fine when I use STS to run the test, but it failes with Infinitest.
If I change ActiveProfiles to dev, then it works well with Infinitest but failes at manual runs.

Comment: If I would use a single property file containing all profiles, then it would be good. And actually, I don't see any reason why I would not do that.

Comment: https://github.com/csorbazoli/sample/tree/master/demo